# class error in java (error: can't find main(String[]) method in class: student)

Tags: java, class, inheritance, multiple-inheritance, inner-classes

I am actually trying to do some basic Java operations an confusing error is occuring:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Student {
    String name, gender;
    int roll;
    int mark1, mark2, mark3;

    void print() {
        System.out.println("Name: " + name);
        System.out.println("Roll: " + roll);
        System.out.println("Gender: " + gender);
    }
}

class MarkStudents extends Student {
    void printData() {
        int total = mark1 + mark2 + mark3;
        System.out.println("Marks\nMaths; " + mark1 + "\nChemistry: " + mark2 + "\nComputer: " + mark3 + "\nTotal: " + total + "\nGrade: ");

        if (total >= 90)
            System.out.print("A");
        else if (total >= 80 && total < 90)
            System.out.print("B");
        else if (total >= 70 && total < 80)
            System.out.print("C");
        else if (total >= 60 && total < 70)
            System.out.print("D");
        else if (total >= 50 && total < 60)
            System.out.print("E");
        else
            System.out.print("F");
    }
}

class StudentDataInheritance {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //create scanner function
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Read student details
        System.out.println("Enter the Student details\nName: ");
        String name = sc.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Roll no: ");
        int roll = sc.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter the gender: ");
        String gender = sc.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Mark1: ");
        int m1 = sc.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Mark2: ");
        int m2 = sc.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Mark3: ");
        int m3 = sc.nextInt();

        MarkStudents m = new MarkStudents();
        m.name = name;
        m.roll = roll;
        m.gender = gender;
        m.mark1 = m1;
        m.mark2 = m2;
        m.mark3 = m3;

        m.print(); // print from p=super class
        m.printdata(); // print from extended
    }
}
```

When I try to run this code :

> `java StudentDataInheritance.java`
> `error: can't find main(String[]) method in class: Student`

But even if I create a Java class with `String[] args`, it pops an error!

Comment: `lass markstudents extends` is it a typo mistake?

Comment: yeah it just an coping mistake thaks for informing :)

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

I see that the name of your file is student.java. And, your main method is present in the Student_data_inheritance class which is not public (i.e. it's not the main class). Move your main method to the student class, because it looks for the main method in the Main class only.

Answer (score -3):

i just resolve the issue by changing filename and class name but still i dont know what cause this issue

Comment: This should be a comment, because this is not an answer. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer